# Excel VBA: How do I create variable data validation based on the column header of the current column?

Tags: vba, excel, validation

EDIT: Code updated to reflect advice presented in comment. I am currently getting a 1004 error on the "Set RefList" line.

**Background**

Sheet 1 or "User Picklist" contains a header row (row 11) with variable titles. The headers will vary based on the client, as will the values that correspond to each header (listed in that same column beginning row 12).

Sheet 2 or "User List" contains the actual users to be uploaded to our system. We frequently see users inputting values that don't exist on the picklist.

**The Objective**

I want to set up flexible data validation on page 2 (User List) where each cell references its own column header (so Range("C13") would reference Range("C11").Value), then search for that value in row 11 of Page 1(User Picklist). When it finds that value, it will use the picklist in that column only as its list of values for data validation.

So if Range("C11").Value on Page 2 is "Location", it does a .Find on row 11 on Page 1, and if it finds Location it will add data validation based on the subsequent values in that column.

**The Code**

```
    'Remove Case Sensitivity
      Option Compare Text

    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim RefRng As Range, NewRng As Range
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("User Picklist")
    Dim RefList As Range
    Set RefRng = ws.Range("A12:T123")
    Set NewRng = Range("A12:T101")
    Dim c As Range

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

For Each c In NewRng

    Dim var1 As String
    Dim var2 As String
    var1 = Cells(11, c.Column).Value
    Dim RngFind As Range
    Set RngFind = ws.Range("A11:ZZ11").Find(var1)

    If Not RngFind Is Nothing Then

    Set RefList = Range(RngFind.Offset(1, 0), RngFind.Offset(1, 0).End(xlDown))


   With c.Validation
        .Delete 'delete previous validation
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="=" & ws.Name & "'!" & RefList.Address
   End With
    End If
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("User List").Calculate
Next

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

As of right now this is crashing my document every time, and my guess is it's because doing this one cell at a time in my For loop is inefficient. I haven't been able to come up with any other way of being able to evaluate the header relative to each cell in my range though.

Any advice is appreciated! :)

Comment: Four thoughts: 1) Change `Variant` data type to string. You are using gobs of memory for nothing with essentially undefined data type. 2) Get rid of `On Error` and trap that nothing is found by adding `If Not RngFind is Nothing` before `Set RefList ...` 3) Turn off calculations while you do this process (and use `Calculate`. Hope any or all of those help in some way. 4) Step through code line-by-line to see where the crash is happening.

Comment: I've updated 1 and 2. 3 I was less sure of, but I updated the code above to reflect. I'm currently getting an error (sometimes it's 1004 and sometimes it's a "value not found error) and VBA highlights the Set RefList line, which is now embedded within the If Not RngFind statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a little better-behaved:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim RefRng As Range, RngFind As Range, NewRng As Range, hdr
    Dim RefList As Range, c As Range, rngHeaders As Range, Msg

    On Error GoTo ErrHandling

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("User Picklist")

    'only deal with the selected cell(s)
    Set NewRng = Application.Intersect(Me.Range("A12:T101"), Target)
    If Not NewRng Is Nothing Then

        Set rngHeaders = ws.Range("A11:ZZ11")

        For Each c In NewRng
            c.Validation.Delete 'delete previous validation
            hdr = Me.Cells(11, c.Column).Value
            If Len(hdr) > 0 Then
                Set RngFind = rngHeaders.Find(hdr, , xlValues, xlWhole)
                'matched header?
                If Not RngFind Is Nothing Then

                    Set RefList = ws.Range(RngFind.Offset(1, 0), _
                                           RngFind.Offset(1, 0).End(xlDown))

                    c.Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
                                     AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                                     Formula1:="='" & ws.Name & "'!" & RefList.Address

                End If 'matched header
            End If 'has header

        Next c
    End If 'in required range

Here:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

ErrHandling:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Msg = "Error # " & Str(Err.Number) & " was generated by " & _
            Err.Source & Chr(13) & "Error Line: " & Erl & Chr(13) & Err.Description
        Debug.Print Msg, , "Error", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End If
    Resume Here
End Sub
```

Comment: Just saw this -- this is perfect! I tried it and it worked exactly as described. Thanks so much!